# How to use Ignorable="d"

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-phone-7

I want to make my usercontrol with yellow background while designing. After design it should stay transparent.
I've tried to use the "Ignore" flag but could not catch how it works.

```
<UserControl x:Class="Abnehmen_Standard.ucRoundButton"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="84" d:DesignWidth="84"
    d:Background="Yellow"
```

Last row does not work.

Can you advice me?

Comment: Try designing your control in a tool called Expression Blend..it allows lots of quick customization to your WPF UIs and also makes use of 'd' namespace, but dont edit manually...

Comment: This Stack Overflow answer might help you as its similar:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843276/xaml-how-to-change-background-color-only-in-design-mode

Comment: thanks but no. I know the isInDesign property. But I wonder how to work with this Ignore "d:" flag. And you gave me the answer that is only possible with blend. Thats all I need to know. :-)

Comment: the http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008 namespace is supported by VS2010 upwards not sure about VS2008, however only for DesignWidth, DesignHeight and DataContext I beleive

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will work if you are using Expression blend. As you can see in your mark up

```
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
```

"d" is used only for expression blend not for visual studio.

Look at [this article](http://geekswithblogs.net/lbugnion/archive/2009/09/05/detecting-design-time-mode-in-wpf-and-silverlight.aspx) if you want to do the same for visual studio, you will have to do some coding for this.

Comment: Thanks Maheep. In this case I will use your link to check out the designmode and I will no more try stuff I cannot solve :-) Great answer!

Comment: It does work in VS, but only for a few things, such as design time data.