# Why doesn't inherit from DynamicResource work (but composition does)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, markup-extensions

I'm implementing my own markup extension to make sure color resources show up properly in the XAML designer in Visual Studio. Basically I have a special version of DynamicResource that returns a certain resource when [in design mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.designerproperties.isindesignmode(v=vs.110).aspx).

My plan was simply to derive from [DynamicResourceExtension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dynamicresourceextension(v=vs.110).aspx) and in [ProvideValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dynamicresourceextension.providevalue(v=vs.110).aspx) do special code when in design mode and just call the base class when in normal mode.

**The problem is** that when I inherit from DynamicResourceExtesion, it doesn't seem like my overridden ProvideValue method gets called.

I'm *strongly* suspecting this is a bug in the framework but I want to post here in case I'm missing something obvious.

---

Here are two version of the same extension, one that works and one that doesn't:

**Composition version - this works as expected**

```
public class MyResourceComposition : MarkupExtension
{
    private readonly DynamicResourceExtension m_dynamicResource = new DynamicResourceExtension();

    public MyResourceComposition()
    {}

    public MyResourceComposition(string resourceKey)
    {
        ResourceKey = resourceKey;
    }

    public object ResourceKey
    {
        get { return m_dynamicResource.ResourceKey; }
        set { m_dynamicResource.ResourceKey = value; }
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        if (Helper.IsInDesignMode)
            return Brushes.Blue;

        return m_dynamicResource.ProvideValue(serviceProvider);
    }
}
```

**Inheritance version - this does not work**

```
public class MyResourceInheritance : DynamicResourceExtension
{
    public MyResourceInheritance()
    {}

    public MyResourceInheritance(string resourceKey)
        :base(resourceKey)
    {
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        if (Helper.IsInDesignMode)
            return Brushes.Blue;

        return base.ProvideValue(serviceProvider);
    }
}
```

**This is the XAML I use to test it:**

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush Color="Green" x:Key="MyBrush" />
</UserControl.Resources>

<StackPanel>
    <!-- This will be green at design time: OK! -->
    <Rectangle Fill="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=MyBrush}" Width="50" Height="50" Margin="8" />
    <!-- This will be green at design time: NOT OK! -->
    <Rectangle Fill="{local:MyResourceInheritance ResourceKey=MyBrush}" Width="50" Height="50" Margin="8" />
    <!-- This will be green at design time: OK! -->
    <Rectangle Fill="{local:MyResourceComposition ResourceKey=MyBrush}" Width="50" Height="50"  Margin="8" />
</StackPanel>
```

For completeness, here's how I figure out if I'm in design mode (but it doesn't matter - even if I unconditionally return `Brushes.Blue` from `ProvideValue()` I get the dynamically looked up value.)

```
internal static class Helper
{
    private static bool? s_isInDesignMode;

    public static bool IsInDesignMode
    {
        get
        {
            if (!s_isInDesignMode.HasValue)
            {
                var prop = DesignerProperties.IsInDesignModeProperty;
                s_isInDesignMode
                    = (bool)DependencyPropertyDescriptor
                                .FromProperty(prop, typeof(FrameworkElement))
                                .Metadata.DefaultValue;
            }

            return s_isInDesignMode.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what if you were to place the inheritance `Rectangle` below the composition `Rectangle`? Perhaps this is an issue with the `IsInDesignMode` property. Maybe it's not being loaded first time?

Comment: Unfortunately not @MikeEason. The MyResourceInheritance rectangle is green regardless of position.

Comment: Might consider a [different way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32872212/create-properties-that-only-apply-on-design-time/32874861#32874861).